Is it possible to wrap the code that is sent for validation in the monaco editor with something?
I want to let the user write typescript code on my react frontend. I use Monaco-editor/react for this.
However, the user only writes code that is inside some wrapper function, and I don't want to force the user to write the entire wrapper function. It wouldn't fit my concept.
So I need that when the user types e.g.:
return 5;

So the monaco editor really validates this:
function wrapper(): number {
    return 5;
}

Because otherwise the monaco editor screams at me that return can only be inside a function.
My understanding is that the monaco editor uses the TS worker in another thread for validation. But when I tried to write my own worker, I always ran into the fact that the monaco editor didn't seem to only call my worker, but also called some of its own default validation, which overloaded mine.
when I tried it without a worker and my code looked something like this:
 const handleEditorDidMount = (editor: any, monaco: Monaco) => {
        editorRef.current = editor
        monacoRef.current = monaco

        const model = editor.getModel()

        const validate = async () => {
            const code = model.getValue()
            const functionStart = "function wrapperFunction(): number {\r\n"
            const functionStartLength = functionStart.length
            let modifiedCode = functionStart + code + "\r\n}"
            console.log("validating", modifiedCode)

            const tempModel = monaco.editor.createModel(modifiedCode, "typescript")
            console.log("tempModel created with uri:", tempModel.uri.toString())

            const uri = tempModel.uri
            const worker = await monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker()
            const client = await worker(uri)

            const semanticDiagnostics = await client.getSemanticDiagnostics(uri.toString())
            const syntacticDiagnostics = await client.getSyntacticDiagnostics(uri.toString())
            const diagnostics = [...semanticDiagnostics, ...syntacticDiagnostics]

            const markers = diagnostics
                .filter((d) => d.start !== undefined && d.length !== undefined)
                .map((d) => {
                    // ...transfer diagnostic to marker - easy
                })

            console.log("markers", markers)

            // there must be a timeout, otherwise the validation will be overridden by some default that is also running there
            setTimeout(() => {
                monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, "typescript", markers)
            }, 1000)

            tempModel.dispose()
        }

        const disposable = model.onDidChangeContent(() => {
            validate()
        })

        return () => {
            disposable.dispose()
        }
    }

    return (
                <MEditor
                    onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
                    value={value ?? ""}
                    options={options}
                    height={height}
                    language={"typescript"}
                />
    )

so i ran into two problems. First, I had to delay setting the markers, and second, it didn't validate some of my code, for example:
return

I don't know why, since return itself is invalid typescript code. (if the function expects a number return type)
So I would need to wrap the code sent for validation with my wrapper function, get the markers and then move them so that they correspond to the code without the wrapper function, because I don't want the user to see the wrapper function in the editor.
Can anyone think of a simpler solution, or what am I doing wrong that the monaco editor constantly sends its default validation and thus overloads mine? And at the same time, why doesn't typescript reveal all the problems to me, such as the fact that the return itself does not contain a number after and therefore it is an invalid typescript code?

It doesn't answer your question, but you can make the specific error message go away by calling monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({ diagnosticCodesToIgnore: [ 1108 ] }), 1108 being “A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.”
